# Left outer join for multiple users

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a database for rounds of golf. I want to see how many rounds each user has per month for the last year.

To do that I created this view `last_12_months` with this code

```sql
SELECT date_part('month'::text, dates.date) AS month,
    date_part('year'::text, dates.date) AS year
FROM ( SELECT (generate_series((now() - '1 year'::interval), now(), '1 mon'::interval))::date AS date) dates;
```

| month | year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 |
| 2 | 2020 |
| and so on to ... |  |
| 12 | 2020 |

The summary view for counting the rounds is very simple also `rounds_count_by_users`

| user_id | month | year | count_all |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020 | 15 |
| 1 | 3 | 2020 | 12 |
| 1 | 5 | 2020 | 10 |
| 2 | 4 | 2020 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 | 2020 | 6 |
| 2 | 9 | 2020 | 3 |

Now for what I want, querying for each user with `left outer join` is quite simple with

```sql
select * 
from last_12_months
left outer join rounds_count_by_users
  on last_12_months.month = rounds_count_by_users.month
  and last_12_months.year = rounds_count_by_users.year
  and user_id = 1
```

Which gives me all the months even when the user has no played rounds. What I would like however is to be able to do this for every user and make a materialized view for easy querying. Is there a nice and easy way of doing this? To be clear this is the final table I want.

This query doesn't work at least, that much I know.

```sql
select * 
from last_12_months
left outer join rounds_count_by_users
  on last_12_months.month = rounds_count_by_users.month
  and last_12_months.year = rounds_count_by_users.year
where user_id = 1
```

| user_id | month | year | count_all |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 3 | 2020 | 12 |
| 1 | 4 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 5 | 2020 | 10 |
| 1 | 6 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 7 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 8 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 9 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 10 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 11 | 2020 | null |
| 1 | 12 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 3 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 4 | 2020 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 6 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 7 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 8 | 2020 | 6 |
| 2 | 9 | 2020 | 3 |
| 2 | 10 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 11 | 2020 | null |
| 2 | 12 | 2020 | null |

I made an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cecc34/1) for this (slightly different values but same schema)

*PS: I know about table aliases and data modeling and that stuff. My question is strictly about how to achieve the final result.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed it to do it this way after help in the comments.
This leaves me with exactly what I wanted.

```sql
with all_rows as (
  select * from view_last_12_months inner join users on true
)

select id as user_id, all_rows.year, all_rows.month, count_all
from all_rows left outer join view_rounds_count_last_year last12 
  on last12.month = all_rows.month 
    and last12.year = all_rows.year
    and all_rows.id = last12.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select * from last_12_months
where (year = year(current_date) - 1 and month >= month(current_date))
      or 
      (year = year(current_date) and month < month(current_date))
```

returns the rows of `last_12_months` for the last 12 months (not including the current month).

This query:

```
select distinct user_id from rounds_count_by_users
```

returns all the distinct `user_id`s (it would be better if these ids where stored in a `users` table).

You must `CROSS` join the above queries and then `LEFT` join `rounds_count_by_users`:

```
select u.user_id, m.month, m.year, r.count_all  
from (
  select * from last_12_months
  where (year = year(current_date) - 1 and month >= month(current_date))
        or 
        (year = year(current_date) and month < month(current_date))
) m cross join (select distinct user_id from rounds_count_by_users) u
left outer join rounds_count_by_users r
on m.month = r.month and m.year = r.year and u.user_id = r.user_id
order by u.user_id, m.month
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5c8f05bd2ad988c4e63c1cc60882ef4).